# Why cannot name a Java package "default"?

Tags: java, package, syntax-error, naming-conventions, directory-structure

In IntelliJ I tried to create a package for my default implementation of services with name `default`:

```
 src
└───  main
    └───  java
        └───  service
            ├───  default
            │   └─── // here I can't create java classes
            │
            ├─── PostService.java
            ├─── SearchService.java
            └─── UserService.java
```

The IDE prompted that you cannot create java classes in this package.

Why can't I create java classes in a package named `default`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`default` is a reserved word. You cannot give your packages, classes, methods, variables, etc. any of the keywords as name.

The full list of reserved words is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that restrictions on using keywords and reserved words apply to package names as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because `default` is a reserved Java Keyword - you cannot use reserved keywords (like `public`, `void` etc) as package names.

Answer (score 1):

`default` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) in Java - it's used for the branch of a `switch` statement when no `case` is matched (and, as @Glains mentioned in the comment - since Java 8 it's also used to provide a default implementation of an interface). Thus, it can't be used as an identifier, in the same way that you can't name you package `package`, `class` `public`, etc.

Comment: Not to forget default methods in interfaces.

Comment: @Glains good point, thanks! Edited that in to my answer too for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot use any of the following as identifiers in your programs.
>   The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not
>   currently used. true, false, and null might seem like keywords, but
>   they are actually literals; you cannot use them as identifiers in your
>   programs.

See list of reserved keywords. [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)